# How to avoid warning when defining member in widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Map _parameters;

  Home([Map params]) {
    _parameters = params;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(_parameters.toString()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

IDE says there is a warning.

```
info: This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields are not final: Home._parameters (must_be_immutable at [hello_flutter_boost] lib/page/home.dart:6)
```

Here is a problem. I have to define `_parameters` to store parameter from `Home()` (constructor) so the widget can get parameters from outside. But it causes a warning.

Is there any way to avoid the warning?

(related issue in GitHub: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36899)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**StatefulWidget**

You should not mutate variables inside your stateless class it is by design immutable that is why there is another type of widget that can permit state mutation which is the stateful widget

so you need to convert your stateless widget into stateful one.

**Code:**

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map parameters;

  Home({this.parameters});

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var _paramater ;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _paramater = widget.parameters;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(_paramater.toString()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where is in your code doing mutation? there is no mutation, answer below is correct, you just did useless conversion to statefull widget

Comment: @ZhichengZhang No worries :)

Comment: looks like really don't understand what are you doing, I'm about your suggestion to convert stateless widget to statefull instead of add final keyword before property

Comment: @Eugene he want to be able to mutate it , if not he had accepted the final keyword solution , you was asking were the mutation in my code happens, the answer is inside initState function , reassigning a variable is considered mutation .

Comment: my question was rhetorical and he didn't ask about mutation, he just wanted to pass parameter from outside, in your code NO mutation, no setState() so it's useless

Comment: If this is the case he should accepted the final keyword solution but he didn't why do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

**StatelessWidget**

Put the word "final" in front of your map declaration, and change the constructor.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map _parameters;

  Home([this._parameters]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(_parameters.toString()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same issue and neither Saed's nor Eric's answers are totally satisfying IMHO (I'm no Dart/Flutter expert).

Using a `StatefulWidget` while your widget won't really change over time, which seems to be OP's case, comes with a performance drop.

Using constructor's initializer list or syntactic sugar won't work if your instance variable needs to be initialized with a more complex code than just `this.x = x`. And you won't be able to initialize the variable in the constructor's body neither of course so you're stuck.

The only workaround I've found is to compute the value of the instance variable outside the widget and pass it as an argument to the widget. I understand the philosophy behind the `StatelessWidget` being `@immutable` but in some cases it breaks the concept of widget being dedicated pieced of work.